# org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, web-services

I have to send HttpRequest to server using api in this manner.

```
json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL+userid+"key"+serverKey,"GET",params);
```

and I am getting this error.

> org.json.JSONException: Value !DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

But When I am sending userID statically like this..

```
 json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(URL+123+"key"+favc56sjdlkht654hatakomn657g4328,"GET",params);
```

> I am getting proper json response.
>
> this is the api I am using.

http://m.sabakuch.com/api/mypost/id/1289/key/fa4cdfa057fdfc19e3470cd7b6ee943a

please let me know what mistake I am doing here??

Comment: there is issue with your web-service as its returning the html page with is not correct json

Comment: you can check the url and see if it is correct or not first :
String url = URL+userid+"key"+serverKey;

Comment: @LinhNguyen this is url... http://m.sabakuch.com/api/mypost/id/1289/key/fa4cdfa057fdfc19e3470cd7b6ee943a

Comment: your url must be : String URL="http://m.sabakuch.com/api/mypost/id/"

String url = URL+key+"/"+serverKey;
 json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET",params);

pls notice the splash symbol :"/"

Comment: @Nilesh yes it is containing HTML too because we have to show user posts . But why it is giving proper response when I am sending userID statically.

Comment: @LinhNguyen not working, still same issue.. :(

Comment: could you pls run the app and get the log url by :
 Log.e("LOG","url:"+url) ;

Comment: @LinhNguyen this is the out put in logcat .. urlhttp://m.sabakuch.com/api/mypost/id/

Comment: please notice the url you pass in param for jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url,"GET",params);  is in lowercase, not the uppercase : URL, because the log cat result is equal with URL.
url = URL+key+"/"+serverKey;